# View full data source in Dataset properties

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, reportviewer

I'm debugging a report (created with VS2012 Report Designer) and need to figure out from where the values are coming. Thus, I need to see the data source for each dataset. Unfortunately, the Dataset properties window is too narrow to show the full name of the data source. This is annoying since we have several data sources whose names begins with the same terms.

I've tried right-clicking, clicking the "New" button and making the window larger but without success. Does anyone know how to view the full data source name? See the attached image for what I'm referring to.

[image]

Comment: Is the value available in the "Server explorer" window, from the View menu?

Comment: I'm not sure. If I go to the Server Explorer window I can see Data Connections (no subitems here), Servers (local computer as subitem, with subitems such as Event Logs and Management Classes) and SharePoint Connections (no subitems here). Where would I find it?

Comment: My Visual Studio 2013 has an entry in "Data connections". Perhaps 2012's Report Builder saves the data elsewhere. Sorry, no better help from me.